# typed-ast nodes evaluation

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

## Preface

There is a [`typed_ast` library](https://pypi.org/project/typed-ast/) which is used for cross-Python AST parsing & processing (e.g. in [`mypy` project](http://mypy-lang.org/)<sup>1</sup>).

## Problem

I wonder if there is a way to compile nodes the same way as it is for standard [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/library/ast.html)?

Because this works

```
import ast

code = compile(ast.parse('print("Hello World!")'), '<ast>', 'exec')
eval(code)  # Hello World!
```

but this

```
from typed_ast import ast3

code = compile(ast3.parse('print("Hello World!")'), '<ast>', 'exec')  # raises exception
eval(code)
```

gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: compile() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or AST object
```

## Analysis

I know there is [a helper class](https://github.com/python/typed_ast/blob/master/typed_ast/conversions.py#L30-L231) for converting between `typed_ast.ast27` and `typed_ast.ast3`, but couldn't found similar for `typed_ast.ast3` -> `ast` conversion.

Also I'm aware of [`typed-astunparse` package](https://pypi.org/project/typed-astunparse), but it creates source code as string, which is not an option because I'm using some hacks that keep AST `compile`'able, but not unparse-parse'able.

And finally there is [`ast3.dump` function](https://github.com/python/typed_ast/blob/master/typed_ast/ast3.py#L112-L139) which docs say that

> ... if evaluation is wanted *annotate_fields* must be set to False...

so it looks like there may be a way to evaluate generated dump string? Or maybe there is a way to load this string from `ast`?

Or should I write my own `ast3.NodeTransformer` class that performs this kind of conversion?

---

<sup>1</sup>: [proof](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/06589112d2513edeb90386613c2f201e72b08059/setup.py#L192)

Answer (score 0):

My solution so far with custom `ast3.NodeTransformer` (tested on **Python3.5**)

```
import ast
from functools import partial
from itertools import chain

from typed_ast import ast3


def to_visitor(cls):
    def none(_):
        return None

    try:
        plain_cls = getattr(ast, cls.__name__)
    except AttributeError:
        # node type is not found in `ast` module, skipping
        return none

    def visit(self, node):
        node = self.generic_visit(node)
        result = plain_cls(*map(partial(getattr, node), plain_cls._fields))
        return ast3.copy_location(result, node)

    return visit


def to_subclasses(cls,
                  *,
                  deep=True):
    result = cls.__subclasses__()
    yield from result
    if not deep:
        return
    subclasses_factory = partial(to_subclasses,
                                 deep=deep)
    yield from chain.from_iterable(map(subclasses_factory, result))


class TypedToPlain(ast3.NodeTransformer):
    visitors = {'visit_' + cls.__name__: to_visitor(cls)
                for cls in set(to_subclasses(ast3.AST))}

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return partial(self.visitors[name], self)

    def generic_visit(self, node):
        for field, old_value in ast3.iter_fields(node):
            if isinstance(old_value, list):
                new_values = []
                for value in old_value:
                    if isinstance(value, ast3.AST):
                        value = self.visit(value)
                        if value is None:
                            continue
                        elif not isinstance(value, ast.AST):
                            new_values.extend(value)
                            continue
                    new_values.append(value)
                old_value[:] = new_values
            elif isinstance(old_value, ast3.AST):
                new_node = self.visit(old_value)
                if new_node is None:
                    delattr(node, field)
                else:
                    setattr(node, field, new_node)
        return node
```

## Test

```
from typed_ast import ast3

code = compile(TypedToPlain().visit(ast3.parse('print("Hello World!")')),
               '<ast>', 'exec')
eval(code)  # Hello World!
```

Comment: won't work on **Python3.3** (there is a difference in `ast.Call` fields)